# React-Native iOS Bundling failed 54ms error: : Error: Unable to resolve module ... node modules

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, node-modules

I suddenly got this error when opening my react native app. please help!

```
iOS Bundling failed 22ms
error: Error: Unable to resolve module  from C:\Users\Maria\helloapp\App.js:  could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
> 1 | import * as React from 'react';
    |                                ^
  2 | import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
  3 | import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
  4 | import CarList from './CarList';
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Maria\helloapp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:158:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Maria\helloapp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Maria\helloapp\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (C:\Users\Maria\helloapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at C:\Users\Maria\helloapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\Maria\helloapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (C:\Users\Maria\helloapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at async addDependency (C:\Users\Maria\helloapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
```

[image: screenshot from expo go]